# Access Value between ranges

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'd like the following population logic built in an Access database:

I have two tables.  The first, `Table1` contains a set of buckets, with a starting and ending value:

```
Start   End   Bucket        
0.00    0.08    1           
0.08    0.16    2           
0.16    0.25    3           
0.25    0.33    4           
0.33    0.41    5           
0.41    0.49    6           
0.49    0.58    7           
0.58    0.66    8           
0.66    0.74    9           
0.74    0.82    10          
0.82    0.90    11          
0.90    0.99    12          
0.99    1.23    13          
1.23    1.48    14          
1.48    1.73    15          
1.73    1.97    16          
1.97    2.22    17          
2.22    2.47    18          
2.47    2.71    19          
2.71    2.96    20          
2.96    5.00    21          
5.00    10.00   22          
10.00   25.00   23          
25.00   101.00  24
```

`Table2` contains values that I need assigned to a bucket by matching the `My Values` column to lie between the `Start` and `End` range in `Table1`:

`Table2` where `Bucket` has been populated with the corresponding `Bucket` value from `Table1`:

```
My values           Bucket 
7.416438356         22
7.416438356         22
7.416438356         22
7.416438356         22
0.252054795         4
0.750684932         10
0.504109589         7
0.504109589         7
0.504109589         7
9.690410959         22
0.504109589         7
0.504109589         7
0.706849315         9
0.504109589         7
1.504109589         15
0.567123288         7
0.504109589         7
0.753424658         10
85.56164384         24
1.482191781         15
2.994520548         21
3.594520548         21
99                  24
0.504109589         7
```

I can populate `Bucket` for `My values` column in Excel easily via the `VLookup` function, but want to be able to do the same using Microsoft Access.

The only solution I can think of is a lot of `IIF()` functions, but that's messy and not classy.

Comment: Is this one or two tables?

Comment: Edited. Yes, they are two seperate tables

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE Table2 
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.[My Values] >= Table1.Start AND Table2.[My Values] < Table1.End
SET Table2.Bucket = Table1.Bucket;
```

Essentially, we get the value from `Table1` by comparing the `My Values` field in `Table2` to see if it is between `Table1.Start` and `Table1.End`

This will update the entire `Table2` in a single statement, and shows the power of set-based approaches to data vs what is referred to as "row by agonizing row" or RBAR.  See https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/ for a great explanation of that.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll try it out and come back with the results.

Comment: I used a SELECT - LEFT JOIN to pull in the bucket, but used your join creterias and it worked. thanks for the help.